Tracking Event Sequence in GA4 for User Actions
The event_bundle_sequence_id variable in GA4, which is used to track the sequence of events, can assign the same value to all events in the same session because the events are sent in batches. This is also true for the event_timestamp variable, as Google sends events in batches for optimization purposes. In Universal Analytics, there was the hit_number variable to track the order of hits.
In this new scenario, is there a field that can be used to distinguish the sequence of events? For example, can this field be used to determine which search was followed by a product click for a specific user? If such a field does not exist, does this functionality need to be developed, and is it possible?
If such a field does not exist, does this functionality need to be developed, and is it possible?
